# Adding frame numbers to a video, along with total frame duration

Tags: ffmpeg, counter, overlay, frame, timecodes

I need to add frame numbers to videos along with total frame duration of the video. It should show the first frame and the last frame, along with the current frame.

In this forum someone had posted a command, which gives the current frame number;
I've used this and this below command works for me:

ffmpeg -i inputvid.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1001: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: fontsize=55: box=1: boxcolor=black: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy D:\Test\outputvid.mp4

But it doesn't show the total frame duration;
Is there a way to add to this command; to show the first frame and last frame of the video as well  (I'm on windows);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope the question is clear now